# Maximize sum of integer entries under a weight constraint

Tags: sorting, tree, constraints, max, graph-algorithm

I have an array of integers. Lets denote it by A. There is another array W containing weights associated with each entry of A.

In other words, associated with each entry A[i] is a certain weight entry W[i]. (Note that the weights are out of a limited set S_w = {w1,w2,w3,w4} so only few possible values)

The problem statement is as follows: Pick a random number of entries out of A such that when summed together, give you the highest value (SUM_A) under the constraint that the sum of their respective weights (SUM_W) doesn't exceed a threshold, W_threshold.

One possibility is brute force: Compute all permutations of A and for each permutation, select first n entries such that their sum weight SUM_W doesn't exceed W_threshold. Finally, the permutation that gives the maximum SUM_A shall be selected. But the complexity of this scheme is very high due to permutation computation step since the length of A is not constrained.

One other (sub-optimal) possibility is to sort A in descending order and then select first n entries such that their SUM_W doesn't exceed W_threshold. This has lower complexity but the result would be suboptimal.

Could someone give me tips if their already exists an algorithm to resolve the above stated problem? Or if anyone has ideas better than the ones I described above. Many thanks

Comment: 0-1 knapsack problem? see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem this will be O(n*w)

Comment: Hey thanks. Exactly what I was lookung for.